# create ngModel based on variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i want to create several inputfields based on the number of answers chosen 1-5 is possible. and want to name the ngModel "answer1" "answer2" "answer3" "answer4" "answer5" based on the number chosen. So if i choose 3 in the selection there should be 3 inputfields with the ngModel name answer1-3.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let number of Object.answers"> //object.answers  is array from 0 to max 4
<ion-label floating>Selection {{number+1}}:</ion-label>
<ion-input  [(ngModel)]="answer[number+1]"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

if i run this code i get the error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined.
How do i get this code to run?

Comment: It's because it's treating it as an array(or object) try doing [(ngModel)]="answer+1" or [(ngModel)]="{{answer+1}}", not sure if it will work though, if it doesn't you have to make answer(or i'll say answers as an array or object

Comment: change `[(ngModel)]="answer[number+1]"` to `[(ngModel)]="answer{{number+1}}"`

Comment: if try [(ngModel)]="answer{{number+1}}" i get following error: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 6 in [answer{{number+1}}] in ng

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways you can solve this. 
By setting answer(or I'll say answers) to be an array or an object

Also to be sure, have an index instead of directly using your number, as you can be uncertain of what it holds

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let number of Object.answers; let i = index;"> //object.answers  is array from 0 to max 4
<ion-label floating>Selection {{number+1}}:</ion-label>
<ion-input  [(ngModel)]="answer[i]"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Ty for your help, but it still doesnt work. Error: cannot read property '0' of undefined. 
Object.answers is already an array containing numbers from 0 to max 4

Comment: [(ngModel)]="number[i]"

Comment: did you declare and initialized variable that you are using in ngModel as an empty array?